# How do I duplicate the default IPV6 routes to a second routing table in order to bypass a VPN?

Tags: routing, ipv6

I have a VPN gateway raspberry pi (running raspberry pi OS) protecting my outgoing traffic from VPN leaks.

I'm running a SOCKS5 proxy (dante-server) on my VPN gateway so that I can punch a hole out of the VPN for specific applications.

I followed these instructions in order to create a second routing table that bypasses the VPN: https://serverfault.com/a/761780

I'm not using cgroups, instead I'm just marking packets based on the owner being the `socks` user. In order to duplicate the routes that would be present without a VPN to the `novpn` routing table (but without the vpn `tun0` routes), I've created a dhclient exit hook, [like this](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/amd64/isc-dhcp-client/4.2.4-7ubuntu12/file/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/rfc3442-classless-routes).

That all works great for ipv4. But for ipv6, in the default routing table I see this:

```
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

When I try to duplicate those to the `novpn` table, it wont let me:

```
user@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip -6 route add fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium table novpn
user@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip -6 route add fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium table novpn
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Why is the system able to create routes in the default routing table that I can't copy to the `novpn` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel can cheat. It doesn't care itself when it automatically adds routes (`proto kernel`) with conflicting values in the same routing table. Those are usually the automatic prefix LAN routes and are exempt from some checks. Userland can't do this: adding in the same routing table the same route on a second interface triggers `File exists`.

You can change the metric so it won't be considered the same route anymore thus avoiding a conflict. This doesn't matter for link-local IPv6 addresses: it's mandatory to specify an interface along when using them so the *eth0* interface won't really have precedence: the case where a choice would have to be done never happens.

```
sudo ip -6 route add fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium table novpn
sudo ip -6 route add fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 257 pref medium table novpn
[...]
```

As the second route has a different metric: 257 instead of 256, it's not the same route anymore and there's no conflict.

It will just be a bit more difficult for automation.

Comment: And how fully same routes works?

Comment: @gapsf their behavior is undefined. This is also a cause of problem for IPv4 when someone uses addresses in the same LAN on two network interfaces: this creates two identical LAN routes (because kernel can cheat) and it can't be predicted which one will be used (that's the first one, but it can vary when you bring interfaces down then back up). Policy routing can help here.

Comment: Actually my answer should have been simpler: there's no need to copy link-local routes, since for IPv6 link-local the interface MUST be specified: there's no way a link-local packet tied to a LAN can go through VPN because of routing. Beside it's not routable (not forwarded).